# How to pass different objects (having same parent) to a constructor and how to identify type of that object in constructor

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inheritance

I have a scenario where I'm sending different objects to a constructor and I have to identify the class of that object and set values  accordingly.

```
Class ABC {
    private long id;
    private SomeClass obj;
    private String xyzName;
    private Date date;
    private EnumType status;
    // And Getters and Setters
} 
Class A extends ABC {
    private String  someOtherId;
    private String type;
    private String model;
    private String manufacturer;
    //and some props and Getters and Setters
}
Class B extends ABC {
    private String someOtherId;
    private String equipName;
    private String model;
    private String serialNo;
    //and some props and Getters and Setters
}
Class C extends ABC {
    private String someOtherId;
    private String materialName;
    private String desc;
    private String serialNo;
    //and some props and Getters and Setters
}
```

> **Note: These are the entity classes**

And In Controller, I'm doing ops like adding, editing, updating(mostly changing statuses) and etc.And every time I do I have to enter or log kind of msg into 
History Class. something like

> From AController
>   historyService.enterLogToHistory(new
>   History(Aobject, EnumType.somestatus));
>
> From BController,
>   historyService.enterLogToHistory(new History(Bobject,
>   EnumType.somestatus));
>
> From CController,
>   historyService.enterLogToHistory(new
>   History(Cobject,EnumType.somestatus));

```
Class History() {
   private long id;
   private Date date;
   private String Status;
   private String Activity; // or msg

   // some other @Transient properties

   History(Object obj) {
    //set above values like by getting values form this obj(using getters)
   }
   History(Object obj, EnumType status) {
   this(obj);
   // set some other @Transient properties by getting values form this obj
     // and set value for msg;
   }
```

}

> So, Now my problem is how to identify that object whether it is A obj,
>   B, obj or C obj because if know the type of object only I can the getters of that obj and I can set values in History constructor.

So, please anyone help me out in this

Comment: To check class of object use `instanceof` keyword. For example: `if (obj instanceof A)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of `instanceof` mess, consider using oveloaded constructors:

```
class History {

    History(A a) {
        // initialize by `A` instance
    }

    History(B b) {
        // initialize by `B` instance
    }

    //...
}
```

This will work if you know classes of all instances on compile time.

---

Another option is to switch to *static factory methods*:

```
public class History {

    // private constructor to hide instance creation
    private History(ABC abc) {
        this.id = abc.getId();
        this.date = new Date(abc.getDate().getTime());
        // ... another common properties
    }

    public History setStatus(Status s) {
        this.status = s;
        return this;
    }

    // public static factory methods to create instances specified by input
    public static History of(A a) {
        History h = new History(a);
        h.type = a.getType();
        // ... properties specific for `A`
        return h;
    }

    public static History of(A a, Status status) {
        return of(a).setStatus(status);
    }

    public static History of(B b) {
        History h = new History(b);
        h.model = b.getModel();
        // ... properties specific for `B`
        return h;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, to create `History` instances, caller invokes:

```
History aHistory = History.of(a);
History bHistory = History.of(b, Status.ACTIVE);
```

The main advantage of such approach is that more stable API is introduced, while it remains flexible for internal refactoring. Imagine, you decide to implement various behavior for `History` of different types, e.g. `VehicleHistory` and `VesselHistory`. So you create those classes extending `History`, override some methods in them and refactor a few `of()` methods in `History` class (so that not `new History()`, but `new VehicleHistory()` is called). As far as you never call constructor externally, for outer code things remain unchanged -- it receives `History` object as before from the same `History.of()` method as before.

Comment: Ohh man ! don't forget the base rule.  _constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor._ Sorry to say the above code will not work.

Comment: If I use Overloading constructors I could the solve the issue but one problem is there will some common attributes where I have to initialize in all overloading constructors which will make repetitive code which may not a good practice. say like this `class History { History(A a) { this.attrX = a.getX(); this.attrY = a.getX();} History(B a){ this.attrX = b.getX();}`

Comment: @DurgaprasadKusuma yes, my fault. I removed second part as it really won't compile. Another option which will cover all your problems will be to make private constructor accepting `ABC` -- to fill common properties, and set of overloaded `of()` or `from()` static methods every of which accepts `A`, `B` or `C`, and maybe some other arguments. Each such method first creates `new History(ABC obj)`, then fills special properties, then returns this `History` object as a result.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the answer. Overloading constructors is good idea actually. It'll be helpful in other scenerios

Comment: The best point about static factory methods is that you never call `new History()` in outer code -- so when later you decide to redesign inner structure, e. g. extend `History` to some `VehicleHistory`, you just change logic in a few `History` methods, keeping API untouched.

Comment: It seems very interesting Can you be more specific or can you implement for the above scenario?I never implemented this _factory method_ kind of thing.

Comment: @DurgaprasadKusuma I did elaborate my answer, hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Seems very promising to fit into my scenario and seems like a best practice. I didn't have tried it yet but hope it helps me. Thanks a lot man for ur effort and ur valuable time.